# Prevent users from creating Work Items that have no parents in Azure Devops(VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops

I want to prevent users from creating work items(tasks) directly. Tasks must only be created by using add child option in a User Story and not directly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Prevent users from creating Work Items that have no parents in Azure Devops(VSTS)

There is a workaround but not full solution, you can check if it work for you.

You can create a rule for the `task` in the process.

`Organization Settings`->`Process`->click Your custom process->click `Task`->`Rules`->New Rule:

[image]

Then we create the `task` directly, you will get the error:

> TF401320: Rule Error for field Related Link Count. Error code:
>   Required, InvalidEmpty.

You have to add **Related work** before you save this task. But at the moment we could not limit the link type of Related work to be only Parent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps. But, the relation between the two Work items should be that of parent and child. Is that possible? in the rules I can see the options of related link count, external link count, hyperlink count but not link count

Comment: @SimranChandel I don't think it's possible to require the relation

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I did not understand what you meant by that. Could you pls explain?

Comment: In the rules you can only force to create a link, but you can't force that the link will be a Parent link.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a parent child relation

Comment: @SimranChandel, Yes, I have said that, you could not limit the link type of Related work to be only Parent, just like Shayki Abramczyk comment. I also don't think it's possible to require the a parent child relation, you have to add it manually.

Comment: This no longer works, "Related Link Count" is no longer an allowed field to select.

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect, but this is my workaround
[image]

Another workaround: using two rules

1. when related link count =0 clear value of **Parent link** custom field which is **required**
2. when related link count =1 set **Parent link** field = Yes