# How to require an issue work-item to have a parent work-item?

Tags: azure-devops

How can I set that issue work-items should be required to have a parent item?

That would be very helpful in tracking work-items that are causing issues.

Thanks

Comment: my workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73489029/9874965

Comment: @ShadiFayed It doesn't work, or it doesn't work anymore, because Related Link Count is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

So far, this action is not supported. We can make a requirement in “Organization Setting”→Process→Rule to restrict creating work item, but there’s no “Related work” and “Parent” option can be selected in “Make required”.

I found there’s already a similar [feature request ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Require-Parent-for-ADO-work-items-by-ru/1500654?space=21&q=require+relate+to+a+work+item+when+create+issue) submitted in Developer Community. If it meets your request, you can vote and add your comments in the ticket.

Comment: Thank You for you response. Do you know if it's possible to add this feature via my own devOps extension?

Comment: @Schnitzler There is a proposal here (still a work in progress): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Require-Parent-for-ADO-work-items-by-ru/1500654#T-N10024533